# Pub/sub dependency on message type causing indirect coupling between publisher and subscriber

Tags: c#

I have an pub/sub mechanism in a C# solution for event aggregation.
While the coupling between publishers and subscribers in theory is low, it seems to me that the messages themselves might introduction tight coupling.

This is what I have done so far:

```
public class A : ISubscribe<StartMessage> {
   void Handle(StartMessage msg){
      ...
   }
}

public class B {
  void PublishStart() {
    eventAggregator.Publish(new StartMessage())
    ...
  }
}
```

which is good because it doesn't depend on magic strings, but no matter where `StartMessage` resides (it being in `A`, `B` or probably more sensible in it's own class) both `A` and `B` will depend on `StartMessage`.

Is there a way of avoiding this without resorting to magic strings?

I have thought about using some interface e.g. `IMessage` that messages implement but then all listeners would be receive `IMessages` and would have to filter on something like `if (IMessage is StartMessage)` which is horrible.

**EDIT:**
A problem is that ViewModels in MVVM-ish patterns that communicate via en EventAggregator will have to depends on specific messages. This means that reusing such VM's can be difficult when adding new messages.

Comment: Why would they have to filter based on if `IMessage` is a `StartMessage`? Would you have other messages, like `EndMessage`? Have you looked at a dependency injection framework like Unity?

Comment: Yes. Potentially an application would consists of an unknown amount of messages. What would DI solve?

Comment: Ýou were a little terse. In my answer below I have implemented a single subscriber class which listens to all messages. Is your intent to have a separate class for each message type? I.e. class `A` in your example would indeed only subscribe to `StartMessage`s? In that case I believe that double dispatch could help.

Answer (score 1):

Answering more generally: I think that it is logically unavoidable that the specific producer of a message as well as the specific consumer/subscriber have a tight dependency on the actual message implementations they produce or consume.

By contrast, The message distribution *framework* can of course be generic and needs no knowledge beyond simple interfaces (i.e. queue opaque subscribers and pass opaque messages to them).

This allows to limit knowledge of message implementation details to the places where they are actually consumed. One way to achieve this is to put subscribers and messages in inheritance hierarchies. Each concrete subscriber type is only concerned with specific message types. **Knowledge about that specific message implementation is only necessary in that specific subscriber class, and in that specific subscriber class no knowledge about any other messages is needed.** (That seemed to be your valid concern.) This makes it possible to extend existing message/subscriber systems: One can add messages and corresponding subscribers without changes to existing code by implementing the appropriate classes, and the pre-existing user code plays well when formerly unknown messages (and their subscribers) are added.

This will, as far as I can see, involve a run time type check, which you seem to dread. To use function overloads is not possible because overload resolution is a compile time feature which cannot be used for types unknown at compile time. Virtual function calls, by contrast, are a run time feature. But the explicit run time check can be made painless if subscribers inherit from a base class which is a template whose type parameter is the message type; the template code implements the message type check for all derived subscribers. Perhaps this example is an inspiration:

```
//// part of the library code for message passing ////////////////////////////

public interface IMessage{}

public interface ISubscribe
{
    void Handle(IMessage msg);
}

/// <summary>
/// A base class for IMessage subscribers who are only
/// interested in a particular message type. 
/// The Handle() funciton performs the type check and 
/// calls HandleImpl() if and only if the message has the proper type
/// given in the type parameter. Derived 
/// subscribers only need to implement HandleImpl().
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="MessageT">The message type the derived subscriber
/// is interested in.</typeparam>
public abstract class SubscriberBaseT<MessageT>: ISubscribe 
       where MessageT: class, IMessage
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Check whether the message is of the type we are interested in.
    /// If yes, call our handling implementation.
    /// Note: No knowledge of specific message types or internals.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="msg">The IMessage to check</param>
    public void Handle(IMessage msg)
    {
        var messageTmsg = msg as MessageT;
        if( msg != null )
        {
            HandleImpl(messageTmsg);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// To be implemented by derived classes. 
    /// Do something with the message type we are concerned about.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="concreteMsg">A message of the type we are
    /// interested in.</param>
    public abstract void HandleImpl(MessageT concreteMsg);
}


//// user code file1.cs  ////////////////////////////

/// <summary>
/// A user defined message
/// </summary>
public class Msg1T: IMessage { /***/ }

/// <summary>
/// A user defined handler interested only in Msg1T messages.
/// Note: No knowledge of other message types.
/// </summary>
public class Msg1SubscrT: SubscriberBaseT<Msg1T>
{
    public override void HandleImpl(Msg1T msg)
    {
        // do something with this particular message
    }
}


//// user code file2.cs  ////////////////////////////

/// <summary>
/// Another user defined message
/// </summary>
public class Msg2T: IMessage { /***/ }

/// <summary>
/// Another user defined handler,
/// interested only in Msg2T messages
/// </summary>
public class Msg2SubscrT: SubscriberBaseT<Msg2T>
{
    public override void HandleImpl(Msg2T msg)
    {
        // do something with this Msg2T
    }
}

//// user code file3.cs  ////////////////////////////
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I agree that the couple seems to be unavoidable. What I ended up doing was to put pub/sub in a wrapper class. In my case I was attempting to re-use ViewModels, and each project using the VM's had their own messages. Now the projects wrap each VM in a message-augmented VM specific to that project.

Answer (score 0):

If there is only a finite number of different message types which are known at compile time you can exploit the virtual dispatching mechanism to different implementations of a `IMessage` interface:

```
interface IMessage
{
    void CallSubscriberHandle(ISubscribe subscriber);
}

class StartMsg: IMessage
{
    public void CallSubscriberHandle(ISubscribe subscr) { subscr.Handle(this); }
}

class ProgressMsg: IMessage
{
    public void CallSubscriberHandle(ISubscribe subscr) { subscr.Handle(this); }
}

class EndMsg: IMessage
{
    public void CallSubscriberHandle(ISubscribe subscr) { subscr.Handle(this); }
}
```

This pattern calls different `Handle()` functions depending on the run time type of the message, because that type is statically known at the point in the code where `Handle` is called. The subscriber must implement a new method for every message type, so these types must be known (or a fallback will be called). This is a tighter coupling than just a one-method interface, but still the message knows only an interface. (If you have a large number of message types or these types are not known at compile time you are out of luck, but I do not see how you get away then without strings or other data criteria.)

All subsriber implementations must implement all `Handle()` overloads:

```
interface ISubscribe
{
    void Handle(IMessage msg);
    void Handle(StartMsg msg);
    //void Handle(ProgressMsg msg); // don't handle this one
    void Handle(EndMsg msg);
}
```

Perhaps somewhat surprisingly, this code results in each message being handled differently:

```
        foreach(IMessage msg in msgList)
        {
            // Use virtual function dispatch in the message instead of
            // a switch/case at the message handler
            msg.CallSubscriberHandle(msgHandler);
        }
```

For completeness here is a working example, not exactly minimal though:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace VirtualDispatchTest
{
    interface ISubscribe
    {
        void Handle(IMessage msg);
        void Handle(StartMsg msg);
        //void Handle(ProgressMsg msg); // don't handle this one
        void Handle(EndMsg msg);
    }

    class MsgHandler: ISubscribe
    {
        // fall back, for unknown message types
        public void Handle(IMessage msg) { Console.Out.WriteLine("I'm not sure what I'm doing right now"); }
        public void Handle(StartMsg sm) { Console.Out.WriteLine("Here we go!"); }

        // Let's make his message type unknown
        //public void Handle(ProgressMsg pm) { Console.Out.WriteLine("Having fun making progress..."); }
        public void Handle(EndMsg em) { Console.Out.WriteLine("Bummer, already over."); }
    }

    interface IMessage
    {
        void CallSubscriberHandle(ISubscribe subscriber);
    }

    class StartMsg: IMessage
    {
        public void CallSubscriberHandle(ISubscribe subscr) { subscr.Handle(this); }
    }

    class ProgressMsg: IMessage
    {
        public void CallSubscriberHandle(ISubscribe subscr) { subscr.Handle(this); }
    }

    class EndMsg: IMessage
    {
        public void CallSubscriberHandle(ISubscribe subscr) { subscr.Handle(this); }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static List<IMessage> msgList = new List<IMessage>();

        static MsgHandler msgHandler = new MsgHandler();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            msgList.Add(new StartMsg());
            msgList.Add(new ProgressMsg());
            msgList.Add(new EndMsg());

            msgList.Add(new StartMsg());
            msgList.Add(new EndMsg());

            foreach(IMessage msg in msgList)
            {
                // Use virtual function dispatch in the message instead of
                // a switch/case at the message handler
                msg.CallSubscriberHandle(msgHandler);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> ```
> Here we go!
> I'm not sure what I'm doing right now
> Bummer, already over.
> Here we go!
> Bummer, already over.
> ```

Comment: There is still a dependency on the actual `IMessage` implementations. I have edited my question to highlight an issue with the sort of dependency. Maybe there should be some kind of message-broker-adapter class.